# Printwriter to print new lines

Tags: java, printwriter

I am printing a text file using Printwriter, in servlets.

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
    writer.print(text);
        }
```

Though this prints the txt file, it is not printing any new lines.

I've tried

```
LINE ="\n"
writer.print(text + LINE);
```

doesn't work.

also tried using println, still no use.

any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br>` tag for html.

```
LINE ="<br>"
writer.print(text + LINE);
```

Comment: @Zedai, then given Rahul a green tick. Which would also tell others the question has been answered.

Comment: I am trying to but stack over flow says that I need to wait for 5 more mins!!

Answer (score 0):

1. For text file we need to set response contentType as `text`: Example:  `response.setContentType("text;charset=UTF-8");`
2. For newLine by `PrintWriter` we need to print by `println`: example:   `out.println("abcd....");`

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you are complicating stuff.. The answer below works fine and is simple.

Comment: What wrong with the above example ? Here we are not putting any manual format... do we understand ?.... well! if that solution is better to me ... please go ahead with that